# Can a product have 2 different stock status?

Tags: stock, inventory

I would got a use case whereby stock is differentiated into own stock and consignment stock.

Consignment stock will only be sellable once the owned stocked is all sold.

Is there a way to implement this? Basically, I want to differentiate the 2 product code or stock for 1 product.

Looking to hear from you!

Answer (score 2):

Magento has everything to have two or even more different stocks, except the implementation.

What I just said? Database tables exist, but the whole code expects to have exactly one stock. There are lots of extension which implement this with more or less other functionality.

I know about this:
https://github.com/magento-hackathon/MultiStock

But I have no clue about the status of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

based on the example of this extension : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-stock-status-by-amasty.html, you may be able to use the attributes to make more than one stock status or product code